# Rails Active Record Object. "Sum" behaves unexpectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am reading [Rails 4 Test Prescriptions](https://pragprog.com/book/nrtest2/rails-4-test-prescriptions). I had an interesting observation regarding to the 'Sum' method. From the book there are two Models: Project and Task

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :tasks
  ...
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  ...
end

#Rspec code
describe "estimates" do
  let(:project) { Project.new }
  let(:newly_done) { Task.new(size: 3, completed_at: 1.day.ago)}
  let(:old_done) { Task.new(size: 2, completed_at: 6.months.ago)}
  let(:small_not_done) { Task.new(size: 1)}
  let(:large_not_done) { Task.new(size: 4)}

  before(:each) do
    project.tasks = [newly_done, old_done, small_not_done, large_not_done]
    othertasks = [newly_done, old_done,small_not_done, large_not_done]

    puts "Size of project is #{project.tasks.sum(&:size)}" # line 1 <- 0
    puts "Size of othertasks is #{othertasks.sum(&:size)}" # line 2 <- 10
  end
end
```

As the comments indicated, line 1 prints 0 and line 2 prints 10 (the expected result). I have also tried to use **let!** in place of let and got the same result.
I am wondering what is the cause of this inconsistent behavior. I am using ruby 2.2 and Rails 4.2.1

**Edit:**
  I have tried:
 1. save project after task is been added

```
   ...
   project.tasks <<  [newly_done, old_done, small_not_done, large_not_done]
   project.save
   ...
```

and 2. using create instead of new

```
      ...
      let(:project) { Project.create }
      let(:newly_done) { Task.create(size: 3, completed_at: 1.day.ago)}
      let(:old_done) { Task.create(size: 2, completed_at: 6.months.ago)}
      let(:small_not_done) { Task.create(size: 1)}
      let(:large_not_done) { Task.create(size: 4)}
      ...
```

and still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to add a to_a before performing aggregation operations. 
  The working code is :

```
 #Rspec code
  describe "estimates" do
    let(:project) { Project.new }
    let(:newly_done) { Task.new(size: 3, completed_at: 1.day.ago)}
    let(:old_done) { Task.new(size: 2, completed_at: 6.months.ago)}
    let(:small_not_done) { Task.new(size: 1)}
    let(:large_not_done) { Task.new(size: 4)}

    before(:each) do
      project.tasks = [newly_done, old_done, small_not_done, large_not_done]
      othertasks = [newly_done, old_done,small_not_done, large_not_done]

      puts "Size of project is #{project.tasks.to_a.sum(&:size)}" # line 1 <- 10
      puts "Size of othertasks is #{othertasks.sum(&:size)}" # line 2 <- 10
    end
  end
```

Notice the **to_a** in line 1.